# Environment variables are always undefined in VueJs application

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables

I am trying to create some environment variables for my application but they are always undefined for some reason. I followed some guides and did the following

Created a file called `.env` added the following into the file

```
VUE_APP_MY_ENV_VARIABLE = myValue
```

In my `App.js` file added the following:

```
beforeMount(){
  console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_MY_ENV_VARIABLE)
}
```

ran npm run serve but the variable always comes as undefined.
I also ran npm run build and npm run serve multiple times but it ain't working for some reason.

Comment: That should be enough. Did you create the file in the project root?  Same dir as `package.json`

Comment: oops, forget about hat. i placed in the src folder.

Comment: That will do it, should be in the project root

Comment: Possibly the same or similar issue (duplicate?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371041/why-my-environnement-variables-not-picked-up-with-create-react-app