# Why my environnement variables not picked up with create React app?

Tags: environment-variables, create-react-app, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dotenv

I am trying to use environment variables in a react app created on WSL. I cannot access the variables from my app. 
Here is what I did:

1. Create a `.env` file at the root folder of my react app (within a client folder of a Rails app)
2. Create a variable: `REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3000/api/v1/`
3. Log the variable in my console: `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL)`
4. Restarted the server

I keep getting an undefined variable.

Am I missing anything related to WSL maybe? I am a bit clueless as I cannot find a similar problem online.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your file is in the wrong directory. See here: [Environment variables are always undefined in VueJs application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61370527/environment-variables-are-always-undefined-in-vuejs-application) (possible duplicate of your question).